# Meaning of Long wavelength modes - strings behave like scalar fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory

I was looking at these lecture notes by Prof. Xi Yin at Harvard PHYS 287A for String theory. https://canvas.harvard.edu/courses/66399/files/folder/Lecture%20notes%20from%20287a

Firstly I can tell my level of understanding of QFT - I have little exposure of it (scalar field theory and till scattering amplitudes and familiar introductory in words about what EFT is, but not whole mathematical aspects of it and not trained in it much concepts like effective field theory, renormalization etc.)

In the below screenshot, what is meant by "long wavelength modes are weakly interacting" ?

As per my understanding, in static gauge, long wavelength mode, - meaning that the string behaves like a scalar field in low energy limit. In low energy limit, nonlinear effects are suppressed. Is it correct way to interprete?

[image]

And also, I found this aspect quite relavant to this, which I previosuly read:
I was looking at Prof. John McGreevy's QFT lecture notes at University of California, in which he explained in first lecture, the transition from discrete to continuum field - through long chain of atoms connected.
https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/f21/2021-215A-lectures.pdf

[image]

Ultimately, my question is: (From McGreevy notes) Klein Gordon equation valid only for low energy (long wavelength mode)?

And regarding Nambu-Goto action in static gauge - is my interpretation correct as I described above?